# What is the best way to maintain shared fields between tables in database?

Tags: database, database-design, data-modeling

I want to create a database for school management system. The database has two tables contain shared fields like **Students** and **Teachers**.
For example, Student table has fields(id, name, phone, class), and Teacher table has fields(id, name, phone, department).

Is it better to make: a table called **Person** which has fields(id, name, phone), Student table has fields(id, person_id, class), and Teacher table has fields(id, person_id, department).

Which of the two ways is better?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Giving a direct answer to this question might be opinion based. There is no generally best strategy to design database.

Theoretical example: if there is a large amount of data you might want to think about performance: what and how you search and joins.

If you search mostly `Students` and `Teachers` you might not create `Person` table and you could search them easily. Then if you would like to search all `Person`s from db you would need to make two queries and a `UNION` between those and with fields that are common to both *types* of `Person`.

If you search also `Person`s more frequently then you might create `Person` table and implement `Teacher` and `Student` to have foreign key to `Person`. Then when searching two last mentioned you would need to make `JOIN` to `Person`.

In real life I do not know if in this use case there is really a big difference. More important is that you select some strategy and follow it in your future decisions in order to keep the desing clear.

However there might come situation where it is need to change the selected strategy still. So theoretically.

Related question [here](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/114313/mysql-performance-union-then-join-or-join-on-each-part-of-the-union)